# Hover overlay box not getting full width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an overlay effect, but when I hover over the link, the inner content does not appear as full width as you can [see from my pen when you hover over the box and the blue pops up](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/qRPNvz)

Here my code:

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <a href="" id="id-1" class="portfolio-link">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <h5>Paragraph</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="" id="id-2" class="portfolio-link">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <h5>Paragraph</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="" id="id-3" class="portfolio-link">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <h5>Paragraph</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="" id="id-4" class="portfolio-link">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <h5>Paragraph</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h5{
  visibility: hidden;
}

div#portfolio {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div#portfolio a,
div#portfolio a > div{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

div#portfolio a { 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
}

div#portfolio a:hover > div{
    background-color: blue;
}

div#portfolio a:hover h5{
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility .5s;
    -webkit-transition: visibility .5s;
}

#id-1{
   background-image: url(images/Sidney-web2web.png);
   background-color: black;
}

#id-2{
   background-image: url(images/Sidney-web2web.png);
   background-color: red;
}
```

How can I make that blue occupy the entire box?

Hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `position:absolute;` inside your hover:

```
div#portfolio a:hover > div{
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
}
```

See full code below:

```css
h5{
  visibility: hidden;
}

div#portfolio {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div#portfolio a,
div#portfolio a > div{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

div#portfolio a { 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
}

div#portfolio a:hover > div{
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
}

div#portfolio a:hover h5{
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility .5s;
    -webkit-transition: visibility .5s;
}

#id-1{
   background-image: url(images/Sidney-web2web.png);
   background-color: black;
}

#id-2{
   background-image: url(images/Sidney-web2web.png);
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio">
    <a href="" id="id-1" class="portfolio-link">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <h5>Paragraph</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="" id="id-2" class="portfolio-link">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <h5>Paragraph</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="" id="id-3" class="portfolio-link">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <h5>Paragraph</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="" id="id-4" class="portfolio-link">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <h5>Paragraph</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Appreciate the support. It works perfectly for what I need

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Simply split this:

```
div#portfolio a,
div#portfolio a > div{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

to this:

```
div#portfolio a {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

div#portfolio a > div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```